# Display special characters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    string root = Server.MapPath("~");
    string path = @"Content\galleries\galleries\";
    DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(root + path + (string)ViewData["Name"]);
    FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.jpg");
    string response = "";
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {

            var array = new Array();
            var galleryname = '@ViewData["Name"]';

            @for (int i = 0; i < FileList.Length; i++)
            {
                string s = @"
                var path = '../Content/galleries/galleries/" + @ViewData["Name"] + @"/" + @FileList[i].Name + @"';
                var thumbpath = '../Content/galleries/galleries/" + @ViewData["Name"] + @"/thumbs/" + @FileList[i].Name + @"';
                array[" + i.ToString() + @"] =
                    {
                        image: path,
                        title: '" + @ViewData["Name"] + @"',
                        thumb: thumbpath,
                        url: path
                    };";
                response += s;
            }
            @response
```

This is my code. I want to dynamically write some javascript code with asp.net. When I print the string 'response' with @response , in page source I can see than all ' characters are changed to & #39; . All paths are bad then. I also tried using Response.Write(s) inside the loop, and ' characters are not changed, but then generated code is placed in the very beginning of the page source, before doctype and of course, nothing works.

How to resolve these issues? Or at least one of them  ;) ? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Instruct to output raw text:

```
@Html.Raw(response)
```